# How to call a MainActivity class from Custom AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

I have a method inside MainActivity named `PlaySong()`, and from MainActivity, I'm calling a custom AlertDialog class like this

```
SongListDialog songlistDialog = new SongListDialog(this, songsList);
songlistDialog.show();
```

how can I call PlaySong() from songlist which is inside the SonglistDialog. Currently I have this ListView and I can track the click on any song using the following code:

```
@OnClick(R.id.card_view)
void onClick() {
     Song song = songs.get(getAdapterPosition());
     dialog.dismiss();

    // here I want to call PlaySong() method which is inside MainActivity
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What is the error of this ?

Comment: the PlaySong(); method is in MainActivity class which is not accessible from custom Dialog class which is a different class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the best way to avoid leaks is to create a listener interface**

```
public interface SongListListener {
   void playSong(Song song);
}
```

**then on your SongListDialog constructor**

```
private final SongListListener mListener;

public SongListDialog(SongListListener listener, ...) {
    mListener = listener;
}


@OnClick(R.id.card_view)
void onClick() {
     Song song = songs.get(getAdapterPosition());
     dialog.dismiss();

    // notify listener
    mListener.PlaySong(song);
}
```

Finally implements SongListListener  in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SongListListener  {
   //...

  @Override
   void playSong(Song song){
   //do whatever you want with the song here
   }
//...
}
```

Comment: Seems you've been faster than me as you've ended up with the same solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback.

```
public interface OnSongSelectedListener{
    void onSongSelected(Song song);
}


// Then in your Activity
SongListDialog songlistDialog = new SongListDialog(this, songsList, songSelectedListener);
songlistDialog.show();
```

Ideally, the Activity itself should implement the interface. So `songSelectedListener` will be `MainActivity.this`.

Then in the onClick you do:

```
void onClick() {
    Song song = songs.get(getAdapterPosition());
    listener.onSongSelected(song); // Return the selected song
    dialog.dismiss();

    // here I want to call PlaySong() method which is inside MainActivity
}
```

Comment: If you are providing this answer to make OP aware of possible context leaks then it might be a great idea to actually not pass the whole context in the first constructor parameter..

Comment: Idk what OP is doing with the context. If it's not stored by the Dialog there is not necessary leaks. But yeah you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the `MainActivity` in `new SongListDialog(this, songsList)` you can directly call `playSong` on it by casting e.g.

```
public SongListDialog(Context ctx, ...) {
    ((MainActivity) ctx).playSong();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> you want to pass context in adapter from your activity and use that context

**((MainActivity)context).playSong();**